# How to copy a specific line in vim from current position?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

How to copy a specific line in vim from current position, without moving to that specific line?
Suppose, in the below code, if my cursor is in line no. 891 and I want to copy a line, say line no. 899. How do I do it without actually moving to the line 899, pressing yy and come back to 891 ?

```
885 int __pm_runtime_idle(struct device *dev, int rpmflags)
886 {
887         unsigned long flags;
888         int retval;
889 
890         might_sleep_if(!(rpmflags & RPM_ASYNC) && !dev->power.irq_safe);
891 
892         if (rpmflags & RPM_GET_PUT) {
893                 if (!atomic_dec_and_test(&dev->power.usage_count))
894                         return 0;
895         }
896 
897         spin_lock_irqsave(&dev->power.lock, flags);
898         retval = rpm_idle(dev, rpmflags);
899         spin_unlock_irqrestore(&dev->power.lock, flags);
900 
901         return retval;
902 }
```

Comment: Is `8jyy8k` too much?

Comment: To use that I should count the number of lines to go down. Isn't it too much ?

Comment: Yeah maybe. Jumping to a line number doesn't sound too exciting either. `<Esc>:899yi` isn't quite as easy to type. Anyway, I don't show line numbers in my vim, so it's even worse for me, but for you may be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the yank command:

```
:899y
```

This will copy line 899 to the unnamed register.

Answer (score 13):

this short cmd will help you

```
:899t.
```

it will copy the line 899 and paste under your cursor line.

**and** without touching the `"` register.

Answer (score 5):

In general

to yank,

```
:line#y
```

to yank & paste in next line

```
:line#t.
```

to delete

```
:line#d
```

All the above can be applied to a block of lines as well..

to yank from line 10 to line 20

```
:10,20y
```

Answer (score 2):

My [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) has a *fetch* mapping that works with relative addressing, which is faster and (especially with `:set relativenumber`) easier than typing the full line number (as in the other answers).

Your particular example would be `8[f` (fetch from 8 lines below the current line).